# Error occurred while installing bzip2-ruby (0.2.7)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler, bzip2

I tried to install `bzip2-ruby` gem using `bundler`, but it throws this output:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bzip2-ruby:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/user10/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for bzlib.h... yes
checking for BZ2_bzWriteOpen() in -lbz2... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bzip2.c
In file included from bzip2.c:5:
/Users/user10/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h" [-W#warnings]
#warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
 ^
bzip2.c:6:10: fatal error: 'version.h' file not found
#include <version.h>
     ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [bzip2.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user10/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@worm_path_finder/gems/bzip2-ruby-0.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user10/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@worm_path_finder/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0/bzip2-ruby-0.2.7/gem_make.out
```

There was a compilation error.

I use `rvm` (`rvm 1.25.14 (stable)`).

I have tried installing gem standalone (`gem install bzip2-ruby -v '0.2.7'`) and with a some previous versions but I got same results.

Answer (score 4):

I found a [working fork](https://github.com/chewi/bzip2-ruby) of `bzip2-ruby` [brianmario issue tracker](https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby/issues/19#issuecomment-41959407).

**Summary**,just update `Gemfile` like this:

```
gem 'bzip2-ruby', :git => 'https://github.com/chewi/bzip2-ruby.git'
```